# fscanf can't read the entire file when file too large

Tags: c, scanf, readfile, memory-reallocation

I am trying to use C to read a large text file (say, a novel with more than ten thousand words) with fscanf, but each time the program will read until a certain point and seemingly reached EOF, while it is way far away from end of file.
Here is my code:

```
void putWordsInArray(){

        FILE* fileToRead;
        char words[1024];
        int singleSize = 0;

        singleWordArray = (char**)malloc(1024*sizeof(char*));
        indexArray1 = (int*)malloc(1024*sizeof(int));
        //read the temp file automatically generated
        fileToRead = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
        while(fscanf(fileToRead, "%s", words) != EOF){

            printf("%s\n", words);
            //the following if-else statement add the word read to the single word array
            //if they are not yet in the array, or increment its count by 1 isf its already there
            int result = -1;
            result = contains(words, singleWordArray, singleSize);
            if(result == -1){
                indexArray1 = (int*)realloc(indexArray1, (singleSize + 1) * sizeof(int));
                singleWordArray = (char**)realloc(singleWordArray, (singleSize + 1) * sizeof(char*));
                singleWordArray[singleSize] = (char*)calloc((strlen(words) + 1), 1024*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(singleWordArray[singleSize], words);
                indexArray1[singleSize] = 1;
                singleSize++;

            }
            else{
                indexArray1[result] += 1;
            }
            //check if the current list contains the incoming word or not
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what had happened here? I believe I have allocated enough memory each time. Thanks to whoever helps.

Comment: Did you run this with your debugger?

Comment: For each new word, you allocate 1024 as many bytes as you need. Perhaps your problem is that you run out of memory? (You don't check the return values of your allocation functions.)

Comment: "I have allocated enough memory each time. " --> This is not known  to be true.  Code attempts to allocate memory, yet code does not check if it was successful.  Check the return value of the various `*alloc()` calls.  Also test `fileToRead`.  Also `fclose(fileToRead)` when done reading.

Comment: "a novel with more than ten thousand words" -- not a very large file, so the sheer size of the file is unlikely to be the problem.